# how to Calculate distance base on lat long mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("5e576bf5d72a185fcf11e03f"),
    "location": {
        "latitude": 27.6648,
        "longitude": 81.5158,
        "city": "Florida",
        "state": "Florida",
        "country": "United State"
    },
    "description": "This is for test",
    "distance" : "100" //Miles
}
```

How can get the record that calculate the minium distance between coordinates tried difference way didn't get success

Comment: Can you be more specific about your requirement and share what u tried till the time

Comment: Your document contains only a single coordinate, what kind of distance you like to calculate? You should not store numeric values as strings.

Comment: base on lat lng get nearest location

Comment: does [$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/index.html#geonear-aggregation) do what you want?

Comment: Yes i tried @geoNear doesn't help me